# How to install connect for use as an executable with bash

Tags: bash, node.js, connect, npm

I've installed Connect via npm but can't access it's executable, how do I install it?

```
$ node -v
v0.4.7
$ npm -v
1.0.6
$ express -v
2.3.4
$ connect -v
-bash: connect: command not found
```

**Update**

I've added it to the `$PATH`:

```
$ npm link connect
../../node_modules/connect -> /Users/Alfred/local/lib/node_modules/connect

export PATH=$HOME/local/lib/node_modules/connect:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile

$PATH
-bash: /Users/Alfred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/Alfred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-
p0@global/bin:/Users/Alfred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2p0/bin:/Users/Alfred/.rvm/bin:/Users     
/Alfred/local/lib/node_modules/connect:/Users/Alfred/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:  
/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/git/bin:/  usr/X11/bin: No such file or     
directory
```

But it still don't work...

Comment: Where is it installed?  Is that directory on your `PATH`?

Comment: No, but how come the others work and not Connect?

Comment: It's installed in: /Users/Alfred/local/lib/node_modules/connect

Comment: I've put in my `$PATH` but it won't help, see update above

Comment: Does it have executable permission bits set?

Comment: How do I check and if it's missing add that?

Comment: @Alfred, I think @Raynos' answer explains what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`node` as a bash executable runs you a node interpreter.

`npm` as a bash executable allows you to use npm to install programs.

`express` as a bash executable sets up boilerplate code for.

`connect` as a bash executable does nothing. This is normal.

All modules do nothing by default. npm, node and express are exceptions.

Note that npm has some kind of API to find the version of connect